# Python run coroutine inside the same coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have a coroutine that if the variable `event_type` is `started` then it doesn't do anything but if the value is `updated` then do the coroutine again in 5 seconds.

```
import asyncio
import aioconsole    
values = 0

async def send_transaction_event_request(event_type):
    values = values + 1
    if event_type == 'started':
        print('The transaction started')
    elif event_type == 'updated':
        while event_type != 'ended' :
            print(values)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await send_transaction_event_request('updated')
    else :
        print('The transaction stopped')


async def console():
    try:
        logging.info("Console started")
        while True:
            comm = await aioconsole.ainput('>')
            if 'send_transaction_event_request' in comm:
                event_type = input('enter the event type :')
                await asyncio.create_task(send_transaction_event_request(event_type))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Caught error")
        print(e)

await console()
```

I run my input asynchronously (which is working) and when I send the `even_type` equal to `started` or `ended` everything works fine but when i send the `event_type` equals to `updated` there's something wrong.

The problem is that the `asyncio.sleep(5)` blocks my asynchronous console so I can never send another request and I need to restart my program.
How can I solve this?

Comment: We need a little more information. How are you running this code? How are you running whatever function is supposed to update `value`?

Comment: @dirn I updated the question so you can have all the code, thanks for your read!

Comment: It is not a good practice to use recursive coroutines. Check out please: https://bugs.python.org/issue34701